# argument doesn't match prototype error in Linux

Tags: c, linux, struct, function-prototypes

I have header file with the following function declaration:

```
extern  getEmailDetailsResult * getemaildetails_5(getEmailDetailsInput *, CLIENT *);
```

In my .C file, the function definition is

```
getEmailDetailsResult* getemaildetails_5(inputParams, rqstp)
    getEmailDetailsInput *inputParams;
    struct svc_req *rqstp;
```

When I compile my program in Unix, compilation is successful. But in Linux (gcc 4.1.2), I get the following error `"error: argument ârqstpâ doesnât match prototype"`. The .h file which has the function prototype is generated by the OS during compilation.
What may be the cause of error in Linux?

Comment: How is `CLIENT` declared?  Does the Linux build stop complaining if you change the `CLIENT` in the `extern` prototype to `struct svc_req`?

Comment: Hi Michael, The header file in which the function prototype is declared is "api.h" which is generated by rpcgen during compilation. Hence, I guess it is not possible to change the prototype definition. In Unix, the api.h generated by rpcgen contains the function prototype as "extern  getEmailDetailsResult * getemaildetails_5();" and the program compiles without errors.

Comment: Even if the files are generated, you may want to arrange to try out the suggestion (or otherwise look into what `CLIENT`is). Knowing what's actually going on is a first step to figuring out how to best fix the problem. Based on your comment, another approach you might take it to figure out why on the Unix system `api.h` has only a function declaration (strictly speaking it's not a prototype), while on Linux a full prototype is generated. A third thing to look at is to see if on Linux you can convince the system to generate the function definition using ANSI/ISO-style parameter declarations.

Comment: By changing the function declaration (modified CLIENT * as "struct svc_req *") in the header file, the error has been cleared. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `struct svc_req *` pointer is not equivalent to the `CLIENT *` pointer.

Comment: Hi Jens, but the .h file is generated by rpcgen during compilation.

Comment: Well, that may be so, but to get down to the root cause you'll have to determine what type a `CLIENT` is. If it is different from a `struct svc_req` that's your problem. You might be using rpcgen improperly, but that's next to impossible to diagnose from afar.

Answer (score 0):

You have two pointers, `struct svc_req *` and `CLIENT *`. You are getting this error because the two pointers each point to a different type. That is a `struct svc_req` is not the same kind of thing as a `CLIENT`, so the two pointers are not compatible.